# Check Access Token validity each time Facebook Apps performing action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it recommended to check user's Access Token validity EACH time an App is performing a graph request/post/delete action?

What if an app is performing like 100 request within a minute? Will there be any performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that’s not recommended.

If the token is *not* valid, you will see that from the response you’ll be getting from the API anyway – so just make the calls you want to make, and check the return values/catch the exceptions that might get thrown.

---

What might be advisable is to check the token’s validity *once* if the user was not active within your app for a longer time, to see whether you have to send them through the login flow again to get a fresh one. (But that only applies if you recognize your re-visiting user by any other means than FB login, because if you have already send them through the login flow to identify them again or use the JS SDK to check that for you automatically, you will already have a fresh access token.)